# Laravel pass subdomain as a value to another route

Tags: laravel

now I have this code

```
    Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.'.env('DOMAIN')], function()
{
    Route::any('/', function($subdomain)
    {
        Route::get('{/subdomain}/{identifier}/{reCreate?}','AController@index');
    });
});
```

I want to pass `{subdomain}` to  `Route::get('{/subdomain}/{identifier}/{reCreate?}','AController@index');` for when call `subdomain.localhost/identifier` I call `AController@index` I should pass the value of `subdomain` to `AController@index`

Answer (score 1):

I think by using `Route::input('subdomain');` you can access the subdomain parameter.

Inside AController:

```
public function index() {
   dd(Route::input('subdomain'));
}
```

Comment: can you give me an example !

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
Route::domain('{account}.myapp.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer thanks guys for your help ,
the answer is just call the route inside `route::group`

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.'.env('DOMAIN')], function()
{
    Route::any('/{identifier}/{reCreate?}','AController@index');
});
```

and inside Controller function `index` I can access the value as normal `function($subdomain)`